# Validating a TLS Certificate Chain Manually

Tags: c#, ssl, cryptography, ssl-certificate, rsa

For the sake of learning, I tried validating manually a TLS certificate chain (signatures only) using C#

I figured out the algorithm should be as follows:

- Compute the hash from the certificate ;
- Read the signed hash value value from the certificate ;
- Perform an RSA.Verify() method on the hash and the signature using the parent public key.

So I tried the following code:

```
        var myCert = new X509Certificate2(@"Z:\springer.com.crt");
        var parentCert = new X509Certificate2(@"Z:\R3.crt");

        var certHash = myCert.GetCertHash(HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);

        var certSignature = new byte[] { 
            0xAA, 0xF7, 0x2A, 0x84, 0x95, 0x17, 0x2E, 0xCD, 0x58, 0x84, 0x66,
            0x9A, 0xC0, 0x0B, 0x3E, 0x13, 0x0C, 0x94, 0x34, 0x35, 0x31, 0x85, 0xA3, 0x43, 0xBC, 0xDA, 0xFC, 0x00, 0x3F, 0xB3, 0x6D, 0x9E,
            0x4A, 0xAB, 0xEE, 0xDB, 0x34, 0xCB, 0xCE, 0x8F, 0xD2, 0x04, 0x73, 0x4B, 0xE7, 0x11, 0x5E, 0x9E, 0xDC, 0x6B, 0x8A, 0xDB, 0xDD,
            0xB2, 0x6B, 0x1A, 0x7C, 0xE3, 0xFA, 0x97, 0xCC, 0xDF, 0x03, 0xAE, 0xFC, 0x41, 0xDC, 0x5D, 0x6E, 0x70, 0x71, 0x2D, 0x67, 0x96,
            0x0D, 0x94, 0xC0, 0x41, 0xD9, 0xD0, 0x4E, 0xD7, 0x88, 0x99, 0xED, 0xDB, 0x84, 0x9D, 0x35, 0x73, 0xB0, 0x4B, 0x0A, 0x28, 0x19,
            0xAE, 0x62, 0xD4, 0xEE, 0x17, 0xF9, 0x83, 0xFA, 0xDF, 0x56, 0xBE, 0xBB, 0xE9, 0x8F, 0x78, 0x85, 0x11, 0x57, 0x0C, 0xC4, 0x46,
            0xEC, 0xDA, 0xE2, 0xD3, 0x14, 0x86, 0xEA, 0x65, 0xC0, 0x19, 0xDA, 0x9B, 0x8D, 0x21, 0x7D, 0x34, 0xBA, 0x0E, 0xD4, 0xC5, 0xD2,
            0x20, 0x32, 0x15, 0xAA, 0x2C, 0x3B, 0x72, 0x95, 0x8E, 0xA7, 0x72, 0x26, 0x99, 0xA0, 0x5F, 0x43, 0xAC, 0xF9, 0x42, 0x91, 0x35,
            0x0C, 0xB0, 0x0E, 0xE9, 0xF4, 0xBC, 0x25, 0x64, 0x59, 0x98, 0x5E, 0x34, 0x65, 0x9B, 0x28, 0x28, 0x3D, 0x88, 0x23, 0x25, 0x00,
            0x97, 0x38, 0xE1, 0x76, 0xBC, 0x74, 0xB9, 0xFF, 0xBD, 0x17, 0x60, 0x1F, 0x07, 0x05, 0xF0, 0xCF, 0xB4, 0x5E, 0x13, 0x8F, 0xBE,
            0x48, 0x52, 0xF2, 0xD7, 0xBA, 0xEC, 0x44, 0xDC, 0x93, 0x7D, 0x16, 0x82, 0x8F, 0xE5, 0xC3, 0x55, 0x31, 0x99, 0x0A, 0xE1, 0xB1,
            0xC4, 0xE4, 0xCE, 0x31, 0xA5, 0x91, 0xFD, 0x71, 0xF6, 0xF7, 0x01, 0x6D, 0x30, 0x2E, 0xFA, 0x30, 0x41, 0x11, 0xBB, 0x96, 0x4B,
            0xA1, 0xF0, 0x10, 0x71, 0x60, 0x07, 0x5B, 0xD2, 0x30, 0xA0, 0xC2, 0x29, 0x0E, 0x71 };

        var result = 
            parentCert.GetRSAPublicKey().VerifyHash(certHash, certSignature, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
```

However, I can't get `result` to return `True`. What's missing?

**Note 1:** I used the TLS Certificate from https://springer.com

**Note 2:** I hardcoded the Certificate's signature value since there is not a method to extract it using the native .NET X509Certificate class, and using BouncyCastle would be overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer:

The `GetCertHash(HashAlgorithmName.SHA256)` function returns the hash of the whole DER (or PEM) certificate file (i.e the hash of the file already containing the signature).

What we need to know first is that  a DER encoded certificate contains the following structure :

```
Certificate  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
 tbsCertificate       TBSCertificate,
 signatureAlgorithm   AlgorithmIdentifier,
 signatureValue       BIT STRING  }
```

We need to calculate the hash of the tbsCertificate (to be signed), not the hash of the whole sequence.

After that, we can compute `certHash = Sha256Sum(tbsCertificate)` so that we can validate this hash with the signature using the parent's public key.

Comment: Great! Please come back in 48h+ and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

The signature you hardcoded does not match [the current certificate](https://crt.sh/?id=8844752122) published by Cert Transparency. Maybe you are [behind a corporate proxy that does traffic inspection](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/2920/1211)?

Verify you have the right signature with `openssl x509 -in springer.com.crt -text -noout`. You should see

```
Signature Value:
    9f:f5:c4:c5:43:00:9e:2c:d0:54:31:3b:6c:10:45:d4:c3:d4:
    77:48:53:e9:4f:08:f5:96:8a:7b:c2:c1:f2:0f:50:66:39:82:
    36:3f:72:85:e1:c8:45:62:5a:19:70:66:54:12:8b:14:b8:1c:
    d6:6e:ae:98:5a:e9:32:85:6b:de:eb:54:d0:44:c6:1f:af:74:
    70:24:c6:a9:25:0d:3e:63:a9:50:97:41:04:1b:36:9f:3c:0f:
    77:c4:c6:4b:f9:27:7e:8f:c1:25:d5:24:4a:fc:72:08:1a:bf:
    f5:eb:eb:c0:8f:08:c4:6b:9e:1d:6e:23:07:f2:c9:95:38:94:
    b9:cb:95:11:45:fc:a1:de:ce:db:f3:4e:31:db:02:3a:0a:94:
    21:84:65:dc:a8:e0:e5:e5:2c:c7:50:af:92:b9:10:15:ec:af:
    1e:10:34:e3:68:8f:78:68:50:00:09:d4:c6:45:e6:66:5a:07:
    ab:38:a0:3f:75:64:41:5e:13:ea:fe:71:af:27:ca:b0:45:f4:
    e9:c6:0a:7f:89:76:19:a4:37:40:62:f5:a5:fd:44:5a:c6:89:
    b8:d5:db:4d:2d:90:ed:36:80:af:d8:c5:61:88:38:5a:ce:79:
    32:0f:15:1a:4a:1f:9e:1a:c2:91:79:88:ab:b3:1a:49:f2:44:
    dd:3b:20:9a
```

And beware that [Springer uses the Let's Encrypt Certificate Authority](https://crt.sh/?q=springer.com) for many of its certificates, and it looks like they rotate their cert every 3 months or so, so make sure you keep your hardcoded signature in sync with the certificate.

Comment: [This is the certificate I used](https://crt.sh/?q=9E2FAAD41CA8E88D54C84FDBBC6D71B7A7F50C073C0B38EAC4C19539E2921201)